# How to get column 4 row 2 data printed from shell script output stored in a variable?

Tags: java, bash, eclipse, shell

I'm storing shell script output in variable ABCD then using echo to print output but I just want column 4 row 2 data.

scrip output is like below

```
name city country    ID   phone   
A     B      C     12  1233
```

using |cut -f4` I'm able to get column 4 all data but

I just want `12` to get printed

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try:

```
echo "name city country    ID   phone   
A     B      C     12  1233" | awk 'NR == 2 {print $4}'
```

Comment: this worked just added | awk 'NR == 2' in last and got 12 printed.

Answer (score 1):

This command could work :

```
tail -n1 file|awk '{print $4}'
```

Or more efficiently as provided by @LéaGris

```
awk 'END{print $4}' file
```

Comment: Since you are using awk, why not using it exclusively? `awk 'END{print $4}' file`

Comment: @LéaGris You're right, it's just 'cause tail (or head) could be interesting for test/debug script, but I'm agree with you

Answer (score 1):

If you strictly need last row's data you can do:

```
*your_script.sh* | cut -f4 | tail -n 1
```

`tail` gives you the last rows of the previous output

- `-n 1` flag means keep only (the last) one row
- `-n +1` can be used if you want to skip (the first) one row, leaving you with all the remaining row data without the header. Since you only have one remaining row, this is redundant

Answer (score 0):

If you need all the lines exept the first, you can with awk:

```
awk '!/name city country/ {print $4}'
```

or just

```
awk 'NR>1 {print $4}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried below and got exact result :
|cut -f4 |  awk 'NR==2